# c# switch keyword used in a different way than I have seen before

Tags: c#

This is a use of the `switch` keyword which I have not seen before:

```
public TestUserType UserType { get; private set; } = TestUserType.None;

public override Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
        {
            var task = this.UserType switch
            {
                TestUserType.Admin => Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(this.Admin)),
                TestUserType.User => Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(this.User)),
                TestUserType.None => Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(this.Anonymous)),
                _ => Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(this.Visitor))
            };
            return task;
        }
```

Can someone explain this use of 'switch'?  I checked the docs, but I only found the usual `switch (var)` usage.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are comparing against.  Are you asking about the newish [switch _expressions_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression) vs switch statements?

Comment: It looks to me that it is switching on the type of `this.UserType`, but I didn't write this code, just trying to understand it.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right, it is a 'switch expression'

Comment: Google 'pattern matching in C#'

Comment: @KirkWoll, If you post as answer, I will accept.

Comment: @GregGum, since I couldn't find a good dup target, I think you're right that an answered question here would be ideal.  I'll put together a brief answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known as a [switch expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression).  Unlike the traditional switch *statements*, switch *expressions* return a value.

Furthermore, they support concepts such as [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/pattern-matching) which is a far more expressive syntax than (used to be) allowed by traditional `case` statements.  But as Hans points out below, the switch statement also supports pattern matching.

Comment: "regular" switch also understands pattern matching (now)

Comment: @HansKeﬆing ah, I thought I double checked that but right you are!

Answer (score 1):

Equivalent in old notation:

```cs
    switch(UserType)
    {
        case TestUserType.Admin: 
            return Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(this.Admin));
        case TestUserType.User:
            return Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(this.User));
        case TestUserType.None:
            return Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(this.Anonymous));
        default:
            return Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(this.Visitor));        
    }
```